# Android Music Application "has stopped" for no reason

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create basic music player for android. Everything seems fine for me but when Im trying to run the application on my mobile phone. It says that it stopped. I cant resolve that problem. Thank you for any help. 
I have tried to take a look at "Logcat" while the app stops but it seems normal for me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
        private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;

        private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
        private TextView selectedFile= null;
        private SeekBar seekbar = null;
        private MediaPlayer player = null;
        private ImageButton playButton = null;
        private ImageButton previousButton = null;
        private  ImageButton nextButton = null;

        private boolean isStarted = true;
        private  String currentFile = "";
        private boolean isMovingseekBar = false;

        private final Handler handler = new Handler();

        private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public  void run() {
                updatePosition();

            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            selectedFile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
            seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
            previousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
            nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);

            player = new MediaPlayer();

            player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
            player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
            seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (null != cursor) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
                setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
                playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
                nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
                previousButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected  void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
            currentFile = (String) view.getTag();
            startPlay(currentFile);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();

            handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();

            player = null;
        }
        private  void startPlay(String file) {
//        Log.i("Selected: ",file);

            selectedFile.setText(file);
            seekbar.setProgress(0);

            player.stop();
            player.reset();

            try {
                player.setDataSource(file);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

            updatePosition();

            isStarted = true;

        }

        private void stopPlay() {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
            seekbar.setProgress(0);

            isStarted = false;
        }
        private void updatePosition() {
            handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

//        seekbar.setSecondaryProgressTintMode(player.getCurrentPosition());
            handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
        }


        private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
                super(context, layout,c,
                        new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                        new int[] {R.id.displayname, R.id.title,R.id.duration});
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
                TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

                name.setText(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                title.setText(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

//            long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
//                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));
//
//            double durationInMin = ((double) durationInMs / 1000.0) / 60.0;

//            durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue();
//
//            duration.setText("" + durationInMin);
//
                view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
            }
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

                bindView(v, context, cursor);

                return v;
            }
        }



        private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick  = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.play: {
                        if (player.isPlaying()) {
                            handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                            player.pause();
                            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                        } else {
                            if (isStarted) {
                                player.start();
                                playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                                updatePosition();
                            } else {
                                startPlay(currentFile);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.next: {
                        int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                        if (seekto > player.getDuration())
                            seekto = player.getDuration();
                        player.start();

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.previous: {
                        int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;

                        if (seekto < 0)
                            seekto = 0;

                        player.pause();
                        player.seekTo(seekto);
                        player.start();

                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        };
        private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlay();
            }
        };

        private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                return false;
            }
        };


        private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMovingseekBar = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fomUser) {
                if (isMovingseekBar) {
                    player.seekTo(progress);
                    Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener", "onProgressChange");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMovingseekBar = true;
            }
        };

    }
```

Logcat "warning"

```
04-06 00:44:39.587 10679-10679/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted 04-06 00:44:39.588 10679-10679/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
```

UPDATED
This pop-up right now

```
04-06 00:49:32.764 3130-3130/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1522968572.746:16192): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=12132 comm="Bg_Shared3" name="boot_id" dev="proc" ino=12061920 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-N950F_8.0.0_0002 audit_filtered
04-06 00:49:32.767 11925-12132/? E/msgr.BootIdReader: Error reading boot_id from procfs
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at X.17G.a(:240349)
        at X.1ex.a(Unknown Source:680)
        at X.0I4.A(Unknown Source:26)
        at X.0IZ.a(:51612)
        at X.0IZ.b(:51631)
        at X.2FF.d(:450319)
        at X.2FF.b(:450310)
        at X.2FF.a(:450272)
        at X.2FD.init(:450217)
        at X.0RK.run(:69037)
        at X.0Mi.run(:60705)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at X.0Nz.run(:62781)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at X.0LN.run(:57215)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at X.0O8.run(:63173)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-06 00:49:32.769 3130-3130/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1522968572.746:16192): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=dbbf9200 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=3787 pid=12132 auid=4294967295 uid=10271 gid=10271 euid=10271 suid=10271 fsuid=10271 egid=10271 sgid=10271 fsgid=10271 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="Bg_Shared3" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1522968572.746:16192): proctitle="com.facebook.orca"
```

Another update: It seems like the problem is in XML file that I called "listitem" and as it says it list MP3 files from phone. Wihtout that file which (and its implementations such as duration, displayname) it does "work" (Open)

"listitem"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/displayname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dip" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: filter logcat for errors and paste the error to the question

Comment: the only "red text" I see there is: 

04-06 00:44:39.587 10679-10679/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
04-06 00:44:39.588 10679-10679/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory 
But the personalist.xml doesnt event exist

Comment: the file you are trying to play is not found .. check what you have stored in the tag of the list item ..

Comment: @Mohammad Isnt there problem with premissions? Because I want to load/get *.mp3 files from storage in phone and load them into the listitem

Comment: have you set read permissions in the manifest ?

Comment: No, I havent. I look for that and find that I have to add those two commands into Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

@Mohammad Also, would you mind helping me little bit please? Im so close to the end of that app, but I cant find the way to load those song (*.mp3) int listitem.

Comment: did you get files from storage ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read from the storage you need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

for writing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if you want to read and write add them both

Comment: Thank you! I just need to read so I have added the Read external. Still having problem to load or find any kind of *.mp3 and list them. Thank you! BIG UPDATE: I got it! Now I only have to write code to ask for permissions from user when he install this app. Thank you!

Comment: if this helped you please check it as answer

Comment: I would love to but I have to have 15points, got 14 already, so when Im gonna hit 15, Ill check! Ill try to write that permission code right now, thank you!

Comment: Can I get little help? So I have managed how to get permission dialog window to ask user if he wants to give me permissions to read storage, and it works, buuuuuuut when I install that application, it open dialog "application has stopped" And then it shows the dialog with permission. I can give Updated code if you want to. Thank you!

Comment: 04-06 02:20:42.397 11452-11714/? E/SingleFileAttributeStore.cpp: Could not read data from the disk

I Have to be one step quicker before that pops up. So I have to manage to install apk, open application and then asks for permissions before it tries to find songs without them and crash. Also, I put:

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[] 
    {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
Right under ONCREATE

Comment: I can't help you without the error log .. try to debug your code , look closely where the error happens

Comment: I cant even get it debugged :/ and Logcat shows tons of code. Sorry about that.

Comment: This answer should provide more details.